# How can I exit the program when user type E and or else V (view)?

Tags: c

I want to end this code in the beginning IF the user enters <kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>e</kbd> or else <kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>v</kbd> to the question:

> Are you sure want to view the Result? If no type '<kbd>E</kbd>' to exit \nIf you want to View Type '<kbd>V</kbd>'

How to do this when the user enters <kbd>e</kbd> it'll exit and if enters <kbd>v</kbd> it'll show the grades?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int marks;
    printf("Enter The Marks:");
    scanf("%d", &marks);
    printf("Are you sure want to view the Result? if no Type 'E'\nIf you want to view Type 'V'");
    if(marks>=90) {
        printf("%d, A+\n");
    }
    else if(marks>=80) {
        printf("%d, A\n");
    }
    else if(marks>=70) {
        printf("%d, B\n");
    }
    else if(marks>=60) {
        printf("%d, C\n");
    }
    else if(marks>=50) {
        printf("%d, S\n");
    }
    else if(marks>=40) {
        printf("%d, W\n");
    }
    else if(marks>=30) {
        printf("%d,Try getting more marks for your exams\n");
    }        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read as a string, check for the special characters/strings, if not try to [convert to an integer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Comment: Observation: `printf("%d, A\n");` (and none of the others) supply an argument for `%d` format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to read a simple int variable since you only want a character. Every character has a ASCII Code so you can use them as an integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int marks;
  int opc;



  printf("Enter The Marks:");
  scanf("%d", &marks);

  printf("Are you sure want to view the Result? if no Type 'E'\nIf you want to view Type 'V'");

  scanf("%d", &opc);


 if(opc == 'V' || opc == 'v'){
            if(marks>=90)
            {
                printf("%d, A+\n");
            }
            else
            if(marks>=80)
            {
                printf("%d, A\n");
            }

            else
            if(marks>=70)
            {
                printf("%d, B\n");
            }
            else
            if(marks>=60)
            {
                printf("%d, C\n");
            }
            else
            if(marks>=50)
            {
            printf("%d, S\n");
            }
            else
            if(marks>=40)
            {
                printf("%d, W\n");
            }
            else
            if(marks>=30)
            {
                printf("%d,Try getting more marks for your exams\n");
            }
}        


return 0;
}
```

Comment: For that to work, you would have to enter the ASCII value for `'V'` etc. The format specifier `%d` will block at alphabetic input.

Comment: For reading a single character, `opc = getchar();` would be better than using `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem, you have to manage the different cases.
To do that, you can use "IF" loops or switchs.

```
if(marks == 'e' || marks =='E')
{
//do something
}
else if(marks == 'v' || marks =='V')
{
//do something
}
```

Why don't using 2 others variables to manage the exit/stay into the program ?

Comment: If you are comparing a single `char`, you would use single-quotes. If you are comparing a string, you need to use `strcmp`.

Comment: For that to work, you would have to enter the ASCII value for `'V'` etc. The format specifier `%d` will block at alphabetic input ...but the question has not been asked at the point that marks were entered. OP wants the missing code filled in.